# Set Image in Camera Preview after OnResume if image was taken before in Android

Tags: android, image, android-camera

I recently created an Android app which provides functionality of Capturing Image(Using Camera Preview & not intents).

Most of the things are sorted out except for one situation.

- I take the picture & save it. Image is currently displayed in the preview.
- Switch to another app(For example Whatsapp Message or something)
- Get back to my app & the preview is lost. Image is not being displayed.

Here's my `onResume()` function:

```
if(camera == null && !isPreviewStopped) {
    Log.d("Camera","Camera View refreshed");
    flPreview.removeAllViews();//Remove view from FrameLayout
    camera = getCameraInstance();
    preview = new CameraPreview(context, camera);//set preview
    flPreview.addView(preview);//Add preview to Frame Layout

}
```

Would it be better to add Image View over it or there's an option to set image from file to preview.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is the perfect way of doing it, but it worked reasonably well. Here's my `onResume()` method updated.

The logic in `onResume()`:

```
   if(camera == null && !isPreviewStopped) {
        Log.d("Camera","Camera View refreshed");
        flPreview.removeAllViews();
        camera = getCameraInstance();
        preview = new CameraPreview(context, camera);//set preview
        flPreview.addView(preview);
    }else if(isPreviewStopped){
        ImageView previewImage = new ImageView(context);
        // Make sure to store file instance in onSaveInstanceState() & restore it as well.
        ByteArrayOutputStream imageOutputStream = ImageCompression.compressImage(fileObjectOfStoredImage.getPath());


        byte[] imageBytes = imageOutputStream.toByteArray();
        previewImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes,0,imageBytes.length));


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        flPreview.addView(previewImage,params);
    }
```

Please let me know if there's a better way to do it. Always ready to learn.